# Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.20.0:test (default-test). An unexpected error occured (return code 1)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, unit-testing, tycho

I am writing unit tests for SWT application. I have 6 plugins for testing. I build the product and run the unit tests from jenkins. Everything was working fine as expected. However from few days jenkins job is failing with below error message:

```
2016-06-14 14:02:43 [INFO] com.prod.xyz.abc.test .............. SUCCESS [02:28 min]
2016-06-14 14:02:43 [INFO] com.prod.xyz.abc.cam.test .......... SUCCESS [02:09 min]
2016-06-14 14:02:43 [INFO] com.prod.xyz.abc.igb.test .......... FAILURE [10:06 min]
2016-06-14 14:02:43 [INFO] com.prod.xyz.abc.igb.sam.test ...... SKIPPED
2016-06-14 14:02:43 [INFO] com.prod.xyz.abc.test .............. SKIPPED
2016-06-14 14:02:43 [INFO] com.prod.xyz.abc.cam.test .......... SKIPPED

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-surefire-plugin:0.20.0:test (default-test) on project com.prod.xyz.abc.igb.test: An unexpected error occured (return code 1). See log for details. -> [Help 1]
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] 
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] 
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] 
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
2016-06-14 14:02:44 [ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :com.prod.xyz.abc.igb.test
```

What is this return code 1. I tried with different tycho versions. My tycho config is as below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/Tests*.java,**/*Tests.java,**/*TestCase.java,**/Test*.java,**/*Test.java</include>
        </includes>
        <argLine>${tycho.testArgLine} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n</argLine>
        <useUIHarness>true</useUIHarness>

        <!-- Kill test JVM if tests take more than 10 minute to finish -->
        <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>600</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
    </configuration>

</plugin>
```

can you please let me know how to solve this problem. THank you.

Comment: Why are using such old tycho version? Most recent 0.25.0?

Comment: may you run this using -X  to enable full debug logging.

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, its the same behavior with 0.25.0 also

Comment: Do you want to "see log for details"? It's worth putting log in question too. Maven prints much more details directly below the point of failure, but you only provide a tail of output.